# Confusion regarding the usage of "till" and "until"

Tags: time-words

Can you explain the difference between the till and until using some examples? I am confused in this. When should I use till? And, When should I use until?

Comment: Can you explain it little more? I have read that thread.

Comment: As the other thread indicates, they are synonyms, yet one (until) is preferred in more formal contexts (such as an academic paper). The other is fine for day-to-day conversation. **There is no difference in meaning**. If you want to know more than that, you'll need to specify in more concrete terms **exactly** what you're asking about.

Comment: Till when should I wait for you? Is it correct?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. _Wait until 3. If I'm not there by then, just go to the theater without me._

Comment: How can I improve my grammatical skills? I am not a beginner for English. But, I do a lot of errors while writing/speaking. I want you to recommend some ways so that I can also improve. Any book/source/way/strategy which you can suggest me for improving speaking/writing skills?

Comment: Have a look at [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english). And come to check from time to time, it regularly gets completed.

Comment: How can you get better at English? How can I get better playing piano? How can a baseball player get more hits? How can a real estate agent sell more houses? By **hard work and practice**; there is no magic potion. Immerse yourself whenever you can (for example, can you get a native English speaker as a roommate?), and ask your friends to correct you when they hear you say something wrong (convince them it would be impolite to **not** correct you, so they don't let things slide just to be polite; explain to them how your goal is to **improve** your English, not just get by with it).

Comment: That's what I am asking you. What should I do on regular basis so as to improve myself? There should be something which must be done on regular basis for getting better at anything. So, that is my question to you. There are many Hindi sentences of which I am not able to do translation while speaking. It goes really embarassing sometimes. I will be thankful if you would suggest me 
something solid.

Comment: @hellodear2 Ask me, I shall help you converting those Hindi sentences into English.

Comment: But ask in chat; don't ask for translation services on the main site. :^)

Comment: When you drink your water by touching your mouth to bottle, and someone asks for the water, then what will you say to him to tell him that it is drunk by you using mouth touched on it? "isse mat pio, ye mera jhoodha paani hai" (Hindi version)

Comment: @J.R you are not answering my question. Fine!!

Comment: I _did_ answer your question: **Practice**. Use your imagination. Pick a Hindi song every day, and translate its lyrics into English for an imaginary penpal. Pick up your local newspaper, and do the same thing with an editorial. Read a book, like Listenever does, and ask questions here when you run into a grammar issue that confuses you.  And be polite and patient with those who are offering to help you – no more double exclamation marks after just 20 minutes of waiting.

Comment: Sorry for that. Listenever "does" or "do"? When I say "he does his job" is correct? OR "he do his job" is correct?

Comment: One person _does_ something, several people _do_ something. As for your mouth-on-the-bottle question, I like it! You should ask that as a new question. (Comments aren't for answering follow-on questions, but feel free to ask a new one.) I'll bet that question would be received quite positively, and get some good answers, too.